# Obtaining the argument text from a carg_t IDA Python object

Tags: ida, decompilation, idapython

I have a decompiled result from calling idaapi.decompile().

From the decompiled result, I obtain the treeitems and loop through them looking for items that are of type cexpr_t and have the opname of "call".

I can then grab the argument list (carglist_t) and I can easily see that I have the call I am looking for based on the number of carg_t items in the list.

What I would like to get is the text belonging to the carg_t object. If I call 'string', it returns None.

How can I do this?

I know that the text can be generated because I can call get_pseudocode on the decompiled result and print the lines of the function. However, I wanted to avoid parsing the function call text and instead have IDA give me each argument since it has already done all of the required parsing.

If it matters, I am running IDA 6.9.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string based on the `carg_t`'s element type (its `ctype_t`).

Let's assume that your `carg_t` instance is a variable named `arg`. Then for example, if `arg.op == cot_var` then the argument's element type is a local variable. You'd get `arg`'s `lvars_t` index via `arg.v.idx` and you can then get that variable's name as follows:

```
func.get_lvars()[arg.v.idx].name
```

Comment: I can confirm that worked for this case. What if the carg_t instance is a cot_cast or a cot_obj? When it is a cot_cast, it will probably look like (char*)&unk_123456 and I need that text so I can parse out the 123456 which will likely be the memory address of a string. When it is a cot_obj, it is likely to be a static string and it is the string that I want.

Comment: For cot_obj, in my case, the answer appears to be idc.GetString( cargtVar.obj_ea, -1, idc.ASCSTR_C ). I am finding the information in part from https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/structcexpr__t.shtml in the Public Attributes section. I am still working on cot_cast.